How can we know if a multinomial coefficient is even or odd

How can we know if a multinomial coefficient is even or odd?

I thought of this question myself when I learnt that we can actually know when a binomial coefficient can be declared even or odd without even calculating it, but failed to generalise it. I searched in Google and found that this question was never asked before.(possibly?)
In Wikipedia, I found this weird looking expression that basically could find how many times a given prime number can divide a multinomial coefficient at maximum (This is a generalization of some theorem called "Kummer's theorem"):
$$\nu_p {n \choose {m_1,\cdots, m_k}}=\dfrac{1}{p-1}\left(n-S_p(n)-\sum_{i=1}^{k}(m_i - S_p(m_i))\right)$$
Where $n=n_0+n_1p+\cdots +n_rp^r$ and $S_p(n)=n_0+\cdots n_r$.(that is, n is represented in base $p$), and $\nu_p(.)$ is the number of times $p$ can divide the thing in parenthesis maximally. I plugged in $p=2$ but then didn't know what to do next.
But that doesn't lead to anywhere. I tried many things that might be a consequence of this, but those were paths that blinds follow.
I tried to write $${n\choose{k_1,\cdots ,k_m} }={k_1\choose k_1}{{k_1+k_2}\choose k_2}\cdots {{k_1+ \cdots +k_m}\choose k_m}$$ but couldn't really do anything. I somehow want to include $\mod 2$, but can't really see how. Some hints will be of great help.
Thanks in advance!

Given that multinomial coefficients can be factorized into binomial coefficients, it would seem like it suffices to test whether any of these binomial coefficients are even (which as you noted can be done without explicit calculation). If any are even, the multinomial coefficient is even; otherwise, the result is odd.

As an example that illustrates the concept in the comment of Semiclassical, note that $$\binom{10}{5,3,2} = \binom{10}{5} \times \binom{10 - 5}{3} \times \binom{10 - 5 - 3}{2}.$$

You can actually work out the complete prime factorization of each factorial in the numerator and denominator pf the multinomial coefficient using Legendre's method
In your application you only need to consider the case where $p=2$.

As an illustrative example of this idea in practice, and as an alternative to the idea expressed in the comment of Semiclassical, immediately following the posted question, you can check whether (for example) $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5,3,2}~$ is even by checking whether (or not) $$v_2(10!) > [ ~v_2(5!) + v_2(3!) + v_2(2!) ~].$$
